# Error while initializing cropper.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop

i am using [Cropper.js](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) to crop photos on my website.i have followed all the steps in the [readme](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropper/blob/v2.3.0/README.md) page,but i am getting some error.the first error i got is **Uncaught ReferenceError: Cropper is not defined**.so i have added the
**var Cropper = window.Cropper** statement.when i reload the page i got another error **Uncaught TypeError: Cropper is not a constructor**.but in this way only they are passing the options to Cropper constructor,couldn't figure it out what is going wrong

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Cropper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/cropper.css">
  <style>
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div>
    <img id="image" src="wallpaper.jpg">
  </div>

  <div id="preview" ></div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../dist/cropper.js"></script>
  <script>
      var Cropper = window.Cropper;
      var image = document.getElementById('image');
      var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        crop: function(e) {
          console.log(e.detail.x);
          console.log(e.detail.y);
          console.log(e.detail.width);
          console.log(e.detail.height);
          console.log(e.detail.rotate);
          console.log(e.detail.scaleX);
          console.log(e.detail.scaleY);
        }
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like you havent included the `cropper.js` file. Are you *certain* that the file is really located at `../dist/cropper.js`? seems very likely that it is not

Comment: In the link you provided to the Cropper example, I don't see any global `Cropper` object, either, so your methodology would fail there too. I suggest you read the documentation a little closer.

Comment: on the page they ask to initialize the cropper like Window.cropper

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Cropper](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) (not to be confused with [Cropper.js](https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/)) is meant to work with jQuery, so you need to use it through a jQuery object like this:

```
  var image = $('#image');
  var cropper = image.cropper({
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    crop: function(e) {
      console.log(e.x);
      console.log(e.y);
      console.log(e.width);
      console.log(e.height);
      console.log(e.rotate);
      console.log(e.scaleX);
      console.log(e.scaleY);
    }
  });
```

The $('#image') is pretty much the same thing as document.getElementById('image') but it returns the image element as a jQuery object which has a lot of useful methods on it. Many plugins like Cropper.js add their own methods to the jQuery object to make them easy to use.

Comment: Hi @peter ,i run the code like the above suggestion.but i got the error  Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Comment: Whoops. Sorry about that. You just need to take the .detail parts out. I edited my answer.

Comment: Actually, Cropper.js is not meant to work with jQuery, but it's sibling project Cropper does. I suggest, in order to avoid keep spreading confusion, that you remove `.js` and add a warning that they're 2 separate sibling projects that actually achieve the same results, and that the OP was using the Cropper.js syntax while he wanted to use the Cropper jQuery plugin one.

Comment: I didn't even notice there was that other non-jquery Clipper. I updated my answer to differentiate between the two. Thanks!